# Python logging working on Windows but not Mac OS

Tags: python, windows, macos, logging

```
# Logging
cur_flname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
LOG_FILENAME = constants.log_dir + os.sep + 'Log_' + cur_flname + '.txt'
util.make_dir_if_missing(constants.log_dir)
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.INFO, filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt="%m-%d %H:%M")  # Logging levels are DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL
# Output to screen
logger = logging.getLogger(cur_flname)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

I use the code above to create a `logger` that I can use in my module to print messages to screen as well simultaneously to a text file.

On Windows, the messages get output to both file and screen. However, on Mac OS X 10.9.5, they only get output to file. I am using Python 2.7.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you show other variables and  especially `constants`? Looks like `constants.log_dir` contains backslashes `\\` so it is misinterpreted on Mac.

Comment: thanks @EugeneLisitsky, `constants.log_dir` looks like this: `'/Users/ri/Documents/Projects//GL/Output//GL//Logs'`

Comment: Ok. I've tried you code, and it logged for me well, except what screen logs are without date severity and other info. Could you check maybe somewhere above sys.stdout or sys.stderr are redirected to /dev/null or another place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it is clear, you have no problem with creating logger name,
log file name and with logging to a file, so I will keep this part simplified to keep my code succinct.

First thing: To me your solution seems correct as `logging.StreamHandler` shall
send output to `sys.stderr` by default. You might have some code around (not
shown in your question), which is modifying `sys.stderr`, or you are running
your code on OSX in such a way, that output to stderr is not shown (but is
really output).

## Solution with `logging`

Put following code into `with_logging.py`:

```
import logging
import sys

logformat = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s"
datefmt = "%m-%d %H:%M"

logging.basicConfig(filename="app.log", level=logging.INFO, filemode="w",
                    format=logformat, datefmt=datefmt)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt=logformat, datefmt=datefmt))

logger = logging.getLogger("app")
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info("information")
logger.warning("warning")


def fun():
    logger.info(" fun inf")
    logger.warning("fun warn")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

Run it: `$ python with_logging.py` and you shall see expected log records (properly formatted)
in log file `app.log` and on `stderr` too.

Note, if you do not see it on `stderr`, something is hiding your stderr
output. To see something, change in `StreamHandler` the stream to `sys.stdout`.

## Solution with `logbook`

`logbook` is python package providing alternative logging means. I am showing it here to show main
difference to stdlib `logging`: with `logbook` the use and configuration seems simpler to me.

### Previous solution rewritten to `with_logbook.py`

```
import logbook
import sys

logformat = ("{record.time:%m-%d %H:%M} {record.level_name} {record.module} - "
             "{record.func_name}: {record.message}")
kwargs = {"level": logbook.INFO, "format_string": logformat, "bubble": True}

logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stderr, **kwargs).push_application()
logbook.FileHandler("app.log", **kwargs).push_application()

logger = logbook.Logger("app")

logger.info("information")
logger.warning("warning")


def fun():
    logger.info(" fun inf")
    logger.warning("fun warn")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

The main difference is, that you do not have to attach handlers to loggers, your loggers simply emit
some log records.

These records will be handled by handlers, if they are put in place. One method
is to create a handler and call `push_application()` on it. This will put the
handler into stack of handlers in use.

As before, we need two handlers, one for the file, another for stderr.

If you run this script `$ python with_logbook.py`, you shall see exactly the same results as
with logging.

### Separate logging setup from module code: `short_logbook.py`

With stdlib `logging` I reall do not like the introductory dances to make the logger work. I want
simply emit some log records and want to do that as simply as possible.

Following example is modification of previous one. Instead of setting up
logging on very beginning of the module, I do it just before the code is run
- inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` (you may do the same on any other
place).

For practical reasons, I separated the module and calling code to two files:

File `funmodule.py`

```
from logbook import Logger

log = Logger(__name__)

log.info("information")
log.warning("warning")


def fun():
    log.info(" fun inf")
    log.warning("fun warn")
```

You can notice, that there are really only two lines of code related to making
logging available.

Then, create the calling code, put into `short_logbook.py`:

```
import sys
import logbook

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logformat = ("{record.time:%m-%d %H:%M} {record.level_name} {record.module}"
                 "- {record.func_name}: {record.message}")
    kwargs = {"level": logbook.INFO, "format_string": logformat, "bubble": True}

    logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stderr, **kwargs).push_application()
    logbook.FileHandler("app.log", **kwargs).push_application()

    from funmodule import fun
    fun()
```

Running the code you will see it working the same way as before, only logger name will be `funmodule`.

Note, that I did the `from funmodule import fun` after the logging was set up. If I did it on the
top if the `short_logbook.py` file, the first two log records from `funmodule.py` would not be seen
as they happen during module import.

**EDIT: added another `logging` solution to have fair comparison**

## One more stdlib `logging` solution

Trying to have fair comparison of `logbook` and `logging` I rewrote final `logbook` example to
`logging`.

`funmodule_logging.py` looks like:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

log.info("information")
log.warning("warning")


def fun():
    log.info(" fun inf")
    log.warning("fun warn")
    log.error("no fun at all")
```

and `short_logging.py` looks as follows:

```
import sys
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logformat = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s"
    datefmt = "%m-%d %H:%M"

    logging.basicConfig(filename="app.log", level=logging.INFO, filemode="w",
                        format=logformat, datefmt=datefmt)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt=logformat, datefmt=datefmt))

    logger = logging.getLogger("funmodule_logging")
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    from funmodule_logging import fun
    fun()
```

Functionality is very similar.

I still strugle with logging. stdlib `logging` is not easy to grasp, but it is in stdlib and offers
some nice things like `logging.config.dictConfig` allowing to configure logging by a dictionary.
`logbook` was much simpler to start with, but is a bit slower at the moment and lacks the
dictConfig. Anyway, these differences are not relevant to your question.

Comment: "I don't know why, but here are 3 versions of some new code I wrote that seem to work" is a pretty poor answer IMO

Comment: @xavier You have probably misunderstood my final note - it is about my feelings about `logging`, not about admitting that my code works, but I do not know why. All the samples above are working examples (install `logbook` package and then you may try all of them) and I can explain you any line if you need. But please, read and test it first before sending your next reaction.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  The question is about "why doesn't my code work on OSX".  Your answer is "I don't know why, maybe there is some other code causing the problem."  That should have been left as a comment, instead of going off into tangents about logging vs. logbook.

Comment: @xavier I got it. You are right, I did not detect exact cause why it did not work on OSX. It would be difficult to force the author providing complete running example. My guess is that the real source of the problem are difficulties to use `logging` library in a simple way - what often results in messy code where nobody understands, what is going on. That is why I used an answer trying to provide cleaner code which shall work. This is the best what I could do (as I am on Linux and do not have access to OSX).